# robot_pose_ekf on a quadcopter

Tags: ros, quadcopter, navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on a controller for a quadcopter. Currently I have 9-DOF IMU data and localization data (just x-y-z). The onboard controller already has an algorithm (DCM) for calculating orientation. However the localization operates at a max frequency of 4Hz or so. Would the robot_pose_ekf package be suitable for fusing the IMU data with this on a quadcopter platform? I performed a brief literature search and it doesn't appear this has been done before with this package, but I have no reason to believe it would not work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28908/robot_pose_ekf-on-a-quadcopter/) by [mrtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1778/mrtc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2012-03-01

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2012-03-07**:
I think it would be best if you described the design problem you're facing in more detail, ie what particular hardware are you using (I'm assuming ArduPilot Mega, right?) and what exactly are you trying to achieve. Would you like to create a quadcopter based SLAM solution, or hold pos indoors? etc

**Comment by [mrtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1778/mrtc/) on 2012-03-07**:
Thanks for the reply Tom. The platform is actually a modified version of AeroQuad (similar in several ways to ArduPilot). For the time being I'm trying to perform position holding indoors. I'm also using the starmac-ros-pkg to provide some of the functionality.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2012-03-09**:
And how exactly is the localization achieved?

**Comment by [mrtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1778/mrtc/) on 2012-03-09**:
Localization is achieved with  an indoor ultrasonic-based triangulation system.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2012-03-14**:
You'll definitely have to republish IMU data as an IMU topic. DCM doesn't give you information about measurement uncertainties (error covariance), which might be a problem. I remember once trying to achieve what you're doing, but failed for some reason (don't remember exactly, sorry). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The robot pose ekf takes in (partial) pose measurements, so you won't be able to directly feed in the IMU accelerations and angular velocities (how did you get to 9 DOF?), but you can feed in the orientation of the IMU.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2012-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-03-07**:
In the hobby market, it seems that 9DOF is the phrase used for 3 rate gyros + 3 linear accels + 3 magnetometers.

**Comment by [mrtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1778/mrtc/) on 2012-03-07**:
mjcarroll's correct, I should have specified.

**Comment by [mrtc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1778/mrtc/) on 2012-03-07**:
The orientation updates much faster (40 Hz or so) than the localization system (4 Hz) but I guess robot_pose_ekf would still be inappropriate for this purpose.

**Comment by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) on 2012-03-12**:
The robot pose ekf indeed only provides a 'best estimate'. See this answer for more details: http://answers.ros.org/question/29228/robot_pose_ekf-ignoring-imu_data